# Create a stacked area plot in ggplot with Strings as X variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart, but my values come out as lines.  Not sure how to do this if my "X" variable is non-numeric.

Reproducible example:

```
data <- read.table(text = "index country variable value
1 Columbia Cm 0.6530000
2 Tanzania Cm 0.7850164
3 Columbia Cc 0.3970000
4 Tanzania Cc 0.7752160
5 Columbia Ci 0.7170000
6 Tanzania Ci 0.6175699
7 Columbia Ca 0.8180000
8 Tanzania Ca 0.9167924")

ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(country),y=value)) + geom_area(aes(color = variable, fill = variable))
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat="identity")`.

Comment: That'll do.  I was hoping there was a way to plot them on the same curve.  So you can see the transition from one value to the other.  You can kind of see this if you put an as.numeric() around country in the aes function.